# Azure - Connect to a remote Linux VM via Azure PowerShell runbooks and input commands

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I'm trying to find a way to ssh into a Linux VM programmatically via our Azure Automation Account (PowerShell runbook) and input commands. Is this possible? I'm only finding info on how to run other PowerShell commands on remote VMs, but in this case it has to be Linux commands.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the shell script on Azure linux VM, you can use the feature  `Custom Script extension`. But it has a limit. If you want to use the way , you need to store your command in a public location (such as Azure blob) then provide the location. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux).

For example

```
$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "andyprivate" -StorageAccountKey ""


$container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name "input" -Context $context

$stream=$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.sh").OpenWrite()
$content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y apache2')
$stream.write($content,0,$content.Length)
$stream.Flush()
$stream.close()


$sas=New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container "input" -Blob "my.sh"  -Permission r -Context $context
$url=$container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.sh").StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + $sas


$protectedSettings = @{"fileUris" = @($url); "commandToExecute" = "sh my.sh"};
Set-AzVMExtension  -ResourceGroupName 'testdata' -Name 'test' -VMName "testdocker"  -Location "eastasia" `
   -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions" -ExtensionType "CustomScript" -ProtectedSettings $protectedSettings -TypeHandlerVersion 2.1
```

[image]

Comment: I will be taking a look at this. Quite the create solution, thanks!

Comment: is it possible to pass arguments to the uploaded script on a blob?

Comment: @Ress Sorry I cannot understand. Could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: I'd like to have arguments be passed to the script, would that be possible? Such as "sh my.sh -flag "argument"

Comment: @Ress You may do that by changing `commandToExecute`.